How to change color of polyester roller blinds?
I want to change the color of my Ikea roller blinds (Fridans). They are made of polyester.

I don't want to use paint, because I'm worried this will cause the polyester to become stiff and unrollable. Is this true?
Then I thought about gluing fabric to the polyester, however I'm also worried that the glue would cause stiffness.
Another option I thought of was to have the blinds remade in a fabric in the appropriate color, cut the polyester off the metal curtain rod, and then glue the fabric to the metal rod. However, which glue would be adhesive enough to glue fabric to metal?

What's my best option? 1, 2, 3 or perhaps another that you have implemented that I haven't thought of? Thanks in advance

the blind material is probably attached with double-sided tape to the roller

@jsotola I don't know, it came attached to the roller. And it's pretty stuck, so I guess it was attached during assembly with some kind of industrial glue.

Why the Fridans specifically? There are other roller blinds which may be available in the color you want.

@KMJ Because I already have these, and I don't want to replace something that's still working fine.  Plus, when I bought them they were a pretty good price for the size of windows I have. I don't think I would find anything cheaper. And then also, I would have to call someone to install a new frame, and I don't want to go through that hassle again.

Makes sense. I second the paint suggestion then. It doesn't have to be stiff.

Truthfully the best option would be to replace the blinds in the color you want.
If you really don't want to do that, I can recommend Vinyl and fabric paint.  I have used this paint on automotive seats and carpeting and it does not make stuff stiff.  It comes in a few different colors, you can google the product yourself.

thanks for the suggestion.. I will try it out
